# Strange crash using UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two different `UIViewController`s.

The **first one** has got a `NSMutableArray` of subscriptions that it loads in a `UITableView`.

The **second controller** do some operations and in some part of the code reload all the subscriptions.

When I open the first Controller I use the `ViewDidAppear` method to reload the table data (subscriptions).
During this operation sometime my app crashes. I think because I reload the table when in background the list of subscriptions is changing.

Is there a way to reload on the fly the table and let the user scroll the table and in the meantime reload it?

**MORE INFO ABOUT THE ERROR**

```
Uncaught exception: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
```

There are 2 subscriptions that are always present... The `TableView` try to access to index 3

**MORE INFO ABOUT THE ERROR**

Comment: Can you post more information about the crash, some code, something that might help us figure a good answer?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` should return `[yourArray count]` and call `[yourTable reloadData]` each time you change your array

Comment: post your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the tableview reload method when the loading of list of subscriptions is finished.
If you are using a separate class to load subscription, you can use a delegate to inform your main view controller that loading of subscription is finished. Else you can use NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the number of rows in section to be the sum total of the objects in your array.

```
return [self.theArrayWithTheData count];
```

Your problem is that when you reload with a different array, its using the old number of rows so when you scroll past its crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Reload Data will help but to avoid crash before calling [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] put a count check for the array index using a global variable for the row count.